# Twillio Failing to send whats app media template message C#

Tags: c#, twilio

Cannot figure out what the issue is with sending media template messages using twillio to a whats app number.

1. I created a media template (Body: Thank you for your purchase)
2. Added Media URL ([https://azure.blah.blah/{{1}}](https://azure.blah.blah/%7B%7B1%7D%7D))
3. Added sample variable (container-path/blob-name)
4. Submitted for approval to whatsapp, template is approved.

Using twillio nugget version 6.18.0 send whatsapp message:

```
            string contentSID = "blah";
        var contentVariables = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<string, Object>()
    {
        {"1", "blah/test.pdf"}
    }, Formatting.Indented);

                var templateOptions = new CreateMessageOptions(new PhoneNumber($"whatsapp:{address}"))
            {
                ContentSid = contentSID,
                MessagingServiceSid = "blah",
                ContentVariables = contentVariables,
                MediaUrl = new List<Uri> { new Uri("https://azure.blah.blah/{{1}}") },
                
            };
            var message = await MessageResource.CreateAsync(templateOptions);
```

Getting invalid media URL exception when sending this.

If i include full url in media url, i am getting 63013 errro from twillio,
If i only include the domain in media url "https://azure.blah.blah/ i receive the sample file i uploaded in the template

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that is required to send whatsapp media message is:

1. ContentSid
2. MessagingServiceSid
3. ContentVariables

Also content type of the media file must be the same as what was set in the sample template that was approved by whatsapp

Only one type of media can be sent per approved variable WhatsApp media template. WhatsApp classifies approved templates into 1 of 3 types of media headers(Image, Video, Document) based on the sample that was submitted. Once the template has been approved another type of media header cannot be sent using the template.